# Array using loops

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing an array using for loop on CodeBlocks.Code is running but the final result is not completely same as expected.

I've tried to change the limits of loops but nothing is working. Everytime the last line of program behaves differently from others.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int testarray[15];

    for(int x=0; x<16; x++){
      testarray[x] = x*10;
    cout << x << "--" << testarray[x] << endl;
}
}
```

The fifteenth element of code is expected to be

15 - 150

but it is showing

150 - 1

rest of the code is fine.

Comment: Write your arrays and loops like this, `int array[N]; for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)` N is the same number in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

You are making error at array `indexing`. Generally array have index from `0` to `n-1`.

If, `int testarray[15];`

Then we can use `testarray[0]` to `testarray[14]`. Not `testarray[15]`.
In your code, you are using `testarray[15]`.

Correct code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int testarray[15];

    for(int x=0; x<15; x++){    // Notice that, i am using 15 here, not 16
      testarray[x] = x*10;
      cout << x << "--" << testarray[x] << endl;
   }
}
```